# Does onSnapshot works when app is closed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does onSnapshot works when app is closed for google cloud firestore in firebase?

Comment: No, when your page is closed so is the connection to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "when [the] app is closed"?